# Trying to crawl a website but dont get <body>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am playing around and want to send myself an email when a new post in on forum thread appears, but when I open the url with urllib.urlopen I get back the webpage but without a page body. Can someone please tell me why this is the case? And how I can get the body?

```
def loadUrl(adress): 
  adress = urllib.unquote(adress)
  print("Loading " + adress)
  socket =urllib.urlopen(adress)
  html = socket.read()
  socket.close()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  return soup


soup = loadUrl("http://de.pokerstrategy.com/forum/thread.php?threadid=498111")
```

Comment: What exactly _do_ you get back? An empty page? Everything up to just before the `body` tag??

Comment: I get back everything except the <body> </body> and whats between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** sorry, I didn't realise that you had posted the url you were trying to retrieve. I get the same response as you, and aren't sure why. I can't see anything in the javascript, as i had suggested below.

I tested your code and it seems to work fine. Perhaps the page you are trying to retrieve generates the body element via javascript or something similar. In this case I believe you can use something like [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to emulate the browser.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, i would recommend to use [Pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery).

```
from pyquery import PyQuery
d = PyQuery("http://de.pokerstrategy.com/forum/thread.php?threadid=498111")

print d("body").html()
```

Comment: pyquery seems to work where urllib or urllib2 didn't. Have you any idea how it functions differently and why this may be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using `BeautifulSoup` with `urllib2`, for example:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
...
html = urlopen(...)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```